# Apache Beam Python ReadFromText Regex

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a situation where I want to read data from GCS for two given days. My folder structure is `sensors/<date>/<hash>/x.csv.gz`, I want to be able to read the files for say '20171104' and '20171105'. Using the regex `sensors/[20171104,20171105]/<hash>/*` doesn't work. Does anyone know the best way to handle this using the beam.io.ReadFromText function ?

Comment: The comma (`,`) is not a valid character in the Cloud Storage URI wildcard syntax. This might work: `sensors/2017110[45]/<hash>/*`. It's definitely not as flexible or explicit. Reference: [Wildcard Names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to read the intended days of data without using the wildcard, but by writing a python function. The idea is to create an array of all the read operations and then to flatten the array and use that as your input to your pipeline.

```
    def read_files(pipeline, intended_day):

        collections = []
        previous_day = (datetime.strptime(intended_day, '%Y%m%d') - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')

        days = [intended_day, previous_day]
        path = "gs://sensors/{}/<hash>/*"
        for day in days:
            try:
                file_name = path.format(day)
                collection = pipeline | ('Read Past for %s' % day) >> beam.io.ReadFromText(file_name)
                collections.append(collection)
            except IOError:
                logging.error("Failed to read for day %s" % day)

        return collections
```

Then call your function in your pipeline like this:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(runner=runner, argv=argv)
intended_day = "20170810"
pcollections = read_files(p, intended_day)
result = ((pcollections | "Flatten sensor" >> beam.Flatten())
           | .....
         )
```